# API Query Doesn't return results when "params" is encoded into a get request but API call works when URL isn't encoded

Tags: python, url, python-requests, urllib

So when I access the API target via Postman with the URL below, it works fine without any issues

```
base_url = https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log?phrase=action:stuck_on_tree+date_of_event:2022-01-11
```

However, when I append the below parameters into my request, the URL comes out differently and I'm no longer able to get results

```
parameters = {
    'action:': 'stuck_on_tree',
    'date_of_event:': '2022-01-11'
}

PAT = asdasdhdhdhhd123123

response = requests.get(base_url, headers={"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {PAT}"}, params=parameters)

print(response.request.url)
#This returns https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log?phrase=&action%3A=stuck_on_tree&date_of_event%3A=2022-01-11
```

I have tried to use:

```
paramters_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters, safe='')
```

And then I updated my response variable below, but the results are still exaxtly the same. I have tried to do some digging but I can't seem to figure out if this an issue because I'm using a dictionary to pass the params, or if there's something else that I'm not able to understand. I'm fairly new to Python.

```
`response = requests.get(base_url, headers={"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {PAT}"}, params=parameters)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base URL should not include part of your query string (`?phrase=`).

Use this for your base URL:

```
https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log
```

For your parameters, use this:

```
parameters = {
    'phrase': 'action:stuck_on_tree+date_of_event:2022-01-11'
}
```

Update

Since you can't URL encode your parameters due to API constraints, you'll have to pass them as a string like so:

```
parameters = 'phrase=action:stuck_on_tree+date_of_event:2022-01-11'
```

Comment: Initially the reason why I didn't throw the "phrase" key into the `parameters` dictionary was because I wanted to be able to create separate keys for the specific parameters to be able to pass values dynamically into the dictionary. Also I tried that method that you suggested, however the issue persists. The url is now:

`https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log?phrase%3A=action%3Astuck_on_tree%2bdate_of_event%3A=2022-01-11`

Is there a way to just ignore all of those encodings and keep the URL like my original base_url?

Comment: @SuperDummy Ensure there is no colon character inside the `'phrase'` key.

Comment: Just tried that and I'm not getting any results at all. No error messages, getting a status 200 OK.

Comment: @SuperDummy - I've updated my answer. You'll have to pass the parameters to requests.get as a plain old string to prevent them from being encoded.

Comment: Hey I ended up figuring it out! Thanks for telling me about the semi colon in my "phrase" key!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ?

```
PAT = "asdasdhdhdhhd123123"

data = parameters
```

this is just an example of authorization request:

```
import requests
endpoint = ".../api/ip"
data = {"ip": "1.1.2.3"}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer MYREALLYLONGTOKENIGOT"}
response = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Yeah I just tried both. When I used `params=params` I got the same results. 
When I used data=params, I only get the base url which is `https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log?phrase=`

Comment: oh sorry,, data = parameters

Comment: So you're saying to add the data=params in my get request right? Like below:
`response = requests.get(base_url, headers={"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {PAT}"}, data=params)`

I've tried this and I still get the same results:
`https://api.cats.net/orgs/CatEmpire/audit-log?phrase=`

Comment: I meant, to change your code, ```response = requests.get(base_url, headers={"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {PAT}"}, data=parameters)```

Comment: Yeah I just tried that. It doesn't appear to be doing anything. What is the intended result? I'm not very familiar with Python, but I haven't seen data using in a get request, I've only seen `"params"` being used

Comment: usually authorization using requests.post(url, headers, data)

Comment: this is just and example: ``` import requests
endpoint = ".../api/ip"
data = {"ip": "1.1.2.3"}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer MYREALLYLONGTOKENIGOT"}

print(requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers).json()) ```

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Yeah in this case, authorization isn't the issue. When I add the parameters from my dictionary into the API get request, the URL of the request appears to be coming out encoded and it's not hitting the API target properly. So I'm trying to figure out how to remove the "=" and the other delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I needed to create a separate key for each parameter like below:

```
params = { 
   'phrase': 'action:stuck_on_tree',
   'date_of_event:': '2022-01-11'
}
```

I'm not sure why I couldn't fit everything into the 'phrase' key, but this works and is also what I was trying to do to begin with because I wanted to be able to pass things dynamically into the params dictionary, so having all of my parameters in one key was going to be an issue. I didn't need to encode or unencode anything. Basically the semi colon was my issue lol. Thanks for all your help @dimz & @john glenn!